# How to sum like numbers in a list python

Tags: python, sum

So I am playing around and trying to sum the like terms only if it is a specific user input term. For instance in a list    `L = [1,2,2,3,4]` and then I say I want the sum for all terms that are 2, and so 2 shows up twice and and i know `2+2=4` so it would return 4.

I am feeling like this is much easier than I am making it out to be, so far:

```
def main():
    L = eval(input("Please enter the list")
    num = eval(input('Enter the number that has like terms'))
    sloppyway = []
    for nums in L:
        if nums == num:
            sloppyway.append(nums)
    return (sum(sloppyway))
```

I think this would work, but I feel like there is a sleeker more elegant way to do it. any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sum` function with a generator expression as following :

```
>>> L = [1,2,2,3,4] 
>>> num=2
>>> sum(i for i in L if i==num)
4
```

Or as a less efficient way you can use `filter` function:

```
>>> sum(filter(lambda x :x==2,L))
4
```

But note that this could be helpful if your condition was more complicated!

Comment: I like the top way of doing it, that was pretty much exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
x= [1,2,2,3,4]
y=2
print sum([k for k in x if k==y])
```

Simply with list comprehension.